# How to upgrade yarn to latest version in nvm?

Tags: yarnpkg

I installed `yarn` with the following instructions [here](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install). However, I still only have version `v1.22.15`. How can I upgrade it to the latest (`v1.22.19`)?

`which yarn` returns `/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/yarn`.